# Build & Release from Jira(Integrated Jira, Github,Jenkins) by picking up the specific commits

Tags: github, jira

I have integrated the Github and JIRA, so whenever I commit with the Jira issue id, the commit will fall under the JIRA issue. For eg) I've the issue id as CA-1 , when I do the Git commit with the commit message as "CA-1 added a new file", the commit will automatically added to the JIRA issue under the tab "Git Commits". By clicking on each issue in Jira we can able to find the list of Git commits.

we have 3 issue/Feature(CA-1,CA-2,CA-3) in Jira with the Git commit as same as issue id. At the time of the Build & Release in Jira, I planned to release only CA-1 and CA-3, Is there any way to pick only those commits(CA-1 and CA-3) and merge to a new branch ?

Git log for the Git branch:

```
   [CA-3] - " ..."
   [CA-2] - " ..."
   [CA-2] - " ..."
   [CA-1] - " ..."
   [CA-1] - " ..."
   [CA-2] - " ..."
   [CA-3] - " ..."
```

Can anyone please help with above scenario.